# Set a value on a field of a object with lightning component

Tags: lightning, inputfield

I develop a lightning component where I use a object as an attribute.

In my lightning controller, I would like to set a value on that object but it doesn't work, nothing happened..

This is my code:

## View:

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Object" />
<lightning:formattedText valule="{!v.account.Name}" />
```

## Lightning controller:

```
let account = component.get("v.account", true);
account.Name = "Test";
component.set("v.account", account);
```

Can you help me please?
I think it doesn't matter but I develop in a community.

Comment: please edit/format your code =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. Your object `account` is not initialized and if you are not doing it in `init`, then you will receive error. If you are not initializing it in JS, then use the format as mentioned in the [other answer by @sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/251037/54851)

   ```
   <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{sobjectType:'Account'}" />
   ```

   If you want to use the declaration as is, then you need to make sure the JS code written is in `init` and that you initialize the `account` there as:

   ```
   let account = {"sobjectType": "Account", "Name": "Test"};
   component.set("v.account", account);
   ```
2. The syntax for `component.get` is not correct, it only expects a `key` to get the value. It should be written as below. Again this is assuming that `account` is already initialized on the component.

   ```
   let account = component.get("v.account");
   ```
3. Unless it's a typo, the attribute name should be `value` here:

   ```
   <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.account.Name}" />
   ```

Comment: It works, thank you.

I have a last question, how can I get my account with the javascript controller?
At the end of the page when the user submit a form, I would like to get my account to do treatment but the result is undefined.

I don't understand because in my lightning component, I see values for fields.

Doing component.get("v.account") ?

How can I format my code?

Comment: Yes - you can retrieve the value of the attribute using`component.get("v.account")`.

Answer (score 1):

Object should not be used for objects (complicated, I know). Select the correct type of object as the type. Also make sure to initialize it, or you'll get an error.

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{sobjectType:'Account'}" />
```

Comment: Ok thank you but it doesn't work, the page doesn't load itself.